# Convert a Set to an Array in Julia

Tags: julia

How can I convert a Set to an Array in Julia?

E.g. I want to transform the following Set to an Array.

```
x = Set([1,2,3])

x
Set{Int64} with 3 elements:
  2
  3
  1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `collect()` function can be used for this. E.g.

```
collect(x)
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 3
 1
```

Notice, however, that the order of the elements has changed. This is because sets are unordered.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [comprehension](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-comprehensions):

```
x = Set(1:5)
@time y = [i for i in x]
> 0.000006 seconds (2 allocations: 112 bytes)
typeof(y)
> Vector{Int64} (alias for Array{Int64, 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the splat operator on sets:

```
julia> [x...]
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 2
 3
 1
```

However, this is slower than `collect`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ ] to create an array.

```
x = Set([1,2,3])
y = [a for a in x]

y

2
3
1

typeof(y)
Vector{Int64} (alias for Array{Int64, 1})
```